# SOQL Query returns too many results

Tags: soql

I am trying to query the below query in my query editor. The below query is suppose to bring only one quote which is 'Q-100' but it returns me all the quotes that contains q-100. for example q-10001, q-10023...

My Query:

```
[ SELECT Quote_Nr__c,Web_Key__c, Approval_Status__c, Id, Presented_Date__c,Valid_Until__c 
  FROM SFDC_520_Quote__c 
  WHERE Quote_Nr__c  LIKE '%Q-100%']
```

Am I missing something in the query.

Comment: I don't understand. your query will return every quote that contains the string `Q-100946` anywhere in it. If you want just one quote use the `=` sign instead of `like`, and avoid wildcards.

Comment: My bad it was suppose to be Q - 100 not Q - 100946

Comment: Yes, I tried using = but it doesn't work and returns me nothing.

Comment: Are you sure there is a record with exactly that name? Did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 4):

Your query, as designed, will bring all quotes that contain the string `Q-100`. To use equality, your query should read

```
[ SELECT Quote_Nr__c,Web_Key__c, Approval_Status__c, Id, Presented_Date__c,Valid_Until__c 
  FROM SFDC_520_Quote__c 
  WHERE Quote_Nr__c = 'Q-100']
```

There is a big difference between `equals` and `like`.

> **=**: Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName equals the specified value in the expression. String comparisons using
>   the equals operator are case-sensitive for unique case-sensitive
>   fields and case-insensitive for all other fields.
>
> **LIKE**: Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName matches the characters of the text string in the specified value. The
>   LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL is similar to the LIKE operator in SQL;
>   it provides a mechanism for matching partial text strings and includes
>   support for wildcards. The % and _ wildcards are supported for the
>   LIKE operator. The % wildcard matches zero or more characters. The _
>   wildcard matches exactly one character. The text string in the
>   specified value must be enclosed in single quotes. 
>   The LIKE operator
>   is supported for string fields only. The LIKE operator performs a
>   case-insensitive match, unlike the case-sensitive matching in SQL. The
>   LIKE operator in SOQL and SOSL supports escaping of special characters
>   % or _. Don’t use the backslash character in a search except to escape
>   a special character. 
>   For example, the following query matches Appleton, Apple, and Appl, but not Bappl `SELECT AccountId, FirstName, lastname FROM Contact WHERE lastname LIKE 'appl%'`

I recommend you read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) article to familiarize yourself with the `WHERE` clause.